# jQuery/Javascript code repetition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use the scrollTop function for my program, but I am finding that I am writing a lot of repetitive code.

This is an example:

```
<div id="table_contents >
    <ul>
        <li id="one"> title One </li>
        <li id="two"> title Two </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div id="content">
    <p id="target_one"> I am content one </p>

    <p id="target_two"> I am content two </p>
</div>
```

If i was to click on 'title One' I want to scroll to 'I am content one'
Likewise for title two and content two.

This is easy enough to do with jQuery/JS

```
$("#one").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#target_one").offset().top -20
        }, 800);
    });
```

But say for example my table of contents has 15 elements in it, and I want to make each clickable to scroll to its content. For this I would have to repeat the above code 15 times for each element.

Is there a better way than that?

Comment: from all the answers below, everyone is using $(this).attr()
What does this do?

Comment: $(this).attr() or $(this).prop() returns or sets the attribute of the element. Read here : http://api.jquery.com/prop/ and http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change your script to :

**Method 1**

```
$("#table_contents").on("click","li",function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#target_"+$(this).prop('id')).offset().top -20
        }, 800);
    });
```

In this method, the `id` of the clicked element will be appended to "target_", to locate the "target id". *This method will work even for the dynamically added `li` elements.*

---

**Method 2** :
**Without ids [but same order]:**

```
$("#table_contents").on("click","li",function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#content p").eq($(this).index()).offset().top -20
        }, 800);
    });
```

in this method, the index of the element `li` is mapped to the index of the `p` elements to locate the scroll location.

And done!!

http://jsfiddle.net/bmL0o9ez/

http://jsfiddle.net/bmL0o9ez/2/

Comment: Still requires managing unique IDs for the list elements and targets.

Comment: @JeanFerreira it appends the id of the clicked element to "target_"

Answer (score 1):

## [*LIVE FIDDLE DEMO*](http://jsfiddle.net/2dcfba1u/)

```
$("#table_contents ul li").click(function () {

    var theIdAttr = $(this).attr("id");

    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#target_" + theIdAttr).offset().top -20
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a more generic selector for type sort of thing where each element requires identical behavior.

```
$("#table_contents li").click(function() {
        var liElement = $(this);
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#target_" + liElement.attr('id')).offset().top -20
        }, 800);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build the id of the paragraph dynamically based on the id of the li.

HTML

  title One
  title Two

```
<div id="content">
    <p id="target_one"> I am content one </p>

    <p id="target_two"> I am content two </p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#table_contents li").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#target_' + $(this).attr('id')).offset().top -20
    }, 800);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it generic, like:

```
$("#table_contents ul li").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#target_'+ $(this).attr("id")).getId.offset().top -20
        }, 800);
    });
```

if you keep the content in order you could even go ultra generic, like:

```
$("#table_contents ul li").click(function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#content:nth-child('+index+')').getId.offset().top -20
        }, 800);
    });
```

Not tested, but it should give you an idea

cheer mate

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that doesn't rely on using IDs at all, but instead uses jQuery's index() function:

```
$("#table_contents li").click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("p").eq($(this).index()).offset().top - 20
    }, 800);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Lr3qsg0j/)**

Answer (score -1):

I do

```
$("#content p").each(function() {
    var heights = [];
    heights.push($(this).offset().top);
});
```

Then do

```
heights[your_target_as_index];
```

Done?